# Google Maps Places Autocomplete missing geometry

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

The Google Maps Places Autocomplete does not work as expected anymore.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

When inserting a search string in the map (for example "ZKM"), it will give some recommendations in the drop down list. In this case it will be "ZKM | Zentrum für Kunst und Medientechnologie Karlsruhe, Lorenzstraße, Karlsruhe, Deutschland". When clicking this item, no marker will be placed on the map!

But when searching for "Karlsruhe" and clicking the first search result "Karlsruhe, Deutschland" the marker is placed correctly.

In the code a function called getPlace() ist called.

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

The place should contain an object "geometry", but it does not.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Was wondering too while playing with the Places API earlier. Many typical places cannot be found via _nearbysearch_. So, you're not alone.

Comment: Bug reported here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7498

Comment: Wow. How could this critical bug exist for over a month now?! Hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it has been fixed by Google :)

Comment: I've found this problem comes and goes.

Comment: today it's here for all french cities :/

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the beginning of the function:

```
if (!place.geometry) {
  return;
}
```

A `PlaceResult` may, but must not have a `geometry`-property.

To clarify how the autocomplete works:

when you type something, the API will request the predictions(to populate the dropdown). Only when you select a place from the dropdown it requests the data(including the geometry) for the particular place.

Obviously there are inconsistencies of the used data(the API shouldn't suggest a place where no informations are accessible), but that's how it is, it may happen that you get a prediction without a place.

Workaround: AFAIK no

Comment: That is right, but when going to https://www.google.de/maps it works fine. When you write "ZKM" it suggests the same place and also sets a marker. So there must be a working solution.

Comment: Why must there be a solution? google.de is not an implementation of the maps-API. There may be e.g. places where the data-owners did  grant access for google.de, but nor for users of the maps-API.

Comment: Well that is strange. When using the geocoding API the location "ZKM" is found and includes the longitude and latitude: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=zkm So one Workaround could be to use the geocoding API and create an own autocomplete component. But I hope there is a simpler way... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Please be sure you set 'geometry' field in autocomplete like this:

`autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'geometry']);`

Comment: It doesn't matter, if there is in fact no 'geometry' for that place even if you request it there will be none.

Comment: It defaults to ALL fields anyway: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the place contains an object "geometry".

To find this, you should use this :

```
autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat() //for the latitude
autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng() //for the longitude
```