# Google Maps v3 places autocomplete shows address, but returns no place result?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, clgeocoder

I have set-up a page using Google maps places autocomplete service.  Below is a screen snapshot of an address being entered into the text field (controlled) by places autocomplete (works fine)...

[image]

When I click on the only option presented by the Google drop down list, the place changed handler is invoked (as it should be) and the following code is executed to get the place result object:

```
var place = m_autocomplete.getPlace();
```

Examining the place object in the debugger reveals that only one property is defined; the name property, below is the place object as a JSON string:

```
{"name":"2701 Riverside Dr, Ottawa, ON K1A 0B1, Canada"}
```

The place object is missing all other properties (ie: no geometry, no address_components, etc) as outlined in the [Google maps documentation for a PlaceResult object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult).

So, I added more code (to fallback) and call the geocoder service directly when the place results object was incomplete, ie:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr }, geocoder_callback_handler);
```

Where addr contained the value from the text field (confirmed via debugger);  The geocoder callback function returns a status of: ZERO_RESULTS

Questions:

1 - Why does the autocomplete service present an address in the drop down list that results in an incomplete place result object?

2 - Why does the geocoder not recognize an address presented by the autocomplete service?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159392/google-maps-places-autocomplete-missing-geometry

Comment: Yes -- I came across that post -- but Google should cleanup their documentation and state whether properties in objects returned by the API will (or will not) exist; or under what conditions some properties will not exist and other will.